# Spark structured streaming change of Kafka brokers - effect on checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, checkpointing

We have a spark structured streaming application running in production with inhouse managed Kafka (lets call it `kafka-inhouse`)

We are deciding to migrate to `aiven kafka cloud`.

Assuming:

1. We consume all messages from `kafka-inhouse`, and then the new messages get published to `aiven kafka cloud`
2. The `path` and the `checkpoint` in S3 where we store the Kafka messages (using the spark streaming app), doesn't change.

Question:

Will the Spark structured streaming seamlessly manage change in Kafka brokers, especially the `checkpointing` once we migrate?